# Unexpected output in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a string, I need to get characters in square bracket

```
declare  @String Varchar(50)
Set @String ='C910-C916[02]'

Select 
    Substring(Rtrim(Ltrim(@String)), CHARINDEX('[', Rtrim(Ltrim(@string))) + 1, (len(@string) - 1)) val3
```

Output:

```
vol3
02]
```

But expected output is

```
 vol3
 02
```

What is wrong in this query?

Comment: Your final parameter in the substring function (which defines the length of the substring you want to take) is `(len(@string)-1)` which is `12`, you only want two. If the length is dynamic you'll have to calculate it.

Comment: The third parameter of `SUBSTRING` is *length*, for which you've supplied `len(@string)-1` (the length of your entire string, minus `1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(50)
SET @String ='C910-C916[02]'

-- output: 02
SELECT SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(@String)), CHARINDEX('[', RTRIM(LTRIM(@String))) + 1, CHARINDEX(']', RTRIM(LTRIM(@String))) - CHARINDEX('[', RTRIM(LTRIM(@String)))-1) val3
```

With this solution you can also get the number in the middle if the text:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(50)
SET @String ='C910-C916[02] Hello World'

-- output: 02
SELECT SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(@String)), CHARINDEX('[', RTRIM(LTRIM(@String))) + 1, CHARINDEX(']', RTRIM(LTRIM(@String))) - CHARINDEX('[', RTRIM(LTRIM(@String)))-1) val3
```

Comment: This is  work fine for me .  Thank you  Sebastian Brosch

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@String,'[','.['),1);
```